# Attempting to upgrade to ArcGIS JS AMD: dojo.map --> array.map generates error

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, dojo, arcgis-server

I have a long JavaScript application modeled on http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/tags/agsjs/1.05/examples/gmapslayer.html which works with ArcGIS JS 2.4.  In attempting to adapt it to AMD and ArcGIS JS 3.7 I have been stuck on one function:

```
        function buildLayerList() {
          var items = array.map(googleLayer.layerInfos, function(info, index) {
            if (info.defaultVisibility) {
              visible.push(info.id);
            }
            var s1 = "<br/><input type='checkbox' class='list_item' " + (info.defaultVisibility ? "checked='checked'" : "") + " id='";
            s1 = s1 + info.id + "' onclick='updateLayerVisibility();' /><label for='" + info.id + "'>" + info.name + "</label>";
            return s1;
          });
          dojo.byId("layer_list").innerHTML = items.join('');
        }
```

The array.map is the update (currently dojo 1.9) to dojo.map in the original (which was dojo 1.05.  I have the correct require declaration ("dojo/_base/array",) and function declaration (array,) for it arranged in the right order, but when I run the code Firebug tells me that "array is not defined."

I am wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue.  In general, I have the rest of the page updated, except for this particular function.

ADDED LATER:
The googleLayer object does exist, but its layerInfos property shows as undefined. The only documentation of that property I can find is this: http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/tags/agsjs/1.05/docs/googlemapslayer/examples.html. The only way I can see this is to change array.map back to dojo.map.

Comment: why not just use [].map() ? aka googleLayer.layerInfos.map()

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand (not an expert as you can probably tell). Dojo says that since Dojo 1.7 use "array" instead of "dojo" in that situation.  Are you saying there is another Dojo option, or is this a way to work around the Dojo?

Comment: [].map has been built into javascript for about 5 years. it's param signature is the same as array.map.call; or in other words, the first argument becomes the method owner and the rest is the same. no need for a lib or special handling...

Comment: OK, I have looked it up and tried various versions.  The one that makes sense to me is replacing the first line in the function with var items = googleLayer.layerInfos.map(function(info, index) {.  Still no luck, though; I get an error that says googleLayer is undefined (which it isn't).

Comment: if it says googleLayer is undefined, it knows what it's talking about.  i'll bet that array is undefined at time of execution as well and that fixing your timing will fix both problems.

Comment: Can you post your entire module?  I would highly suspect that your dependencies and function arguments are not lining up as you expect.  RE @dandavis: if the application needs to support IE < 9, it cannot rely on ES5 Array methods.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro: the es5 array methods can be seamlessly dropped-in for any browser in a kb or two. if you only care about old IE and not ancient other browsers, putting the script import behind a conditional comment is a great way to affect only those who need affecting...

Comment: @dandavis Sure, that is one approach, but it is tangential to the question.  Dojo already offers array iteration methods in the `dojo/_base/array` module and that is what the OP is trying to use.  I am guessing that the `array` variable is not what he/she thinks it is.  (I can only guess, because we can't see the `require` or `define` call in its entirety.)

Comment: It's now evident that the timing problem is the problem. I was wondering if eliminating a dependency solved the problem, which it did not, thus indicating a lack of requirements. I already noted that if using [].map didn't help, then it wasn't needed as the two should be basically interchangeable...